# Compiling libsndfile, and it does not find FLAC

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, flac, intel-edison, libsndfile

I am trying to cross-compile libsndfile for use on an intel edison, with flac capabilities. I have successfully compiled FLAC, OGG, and VORBIS into my cross toolchain but when I run `./configure` it gives me the following output:

```
checking for pkg-config... /opt/poky-edison/1.7.3/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for flac >= 1.3.1 ... no
checking for ogg >= 1.1.3 ... yes
checking for vorbis >= 1.2.3 ... yes
checking for vorbisenc >= 1.2.3 ... yes

configure: WARNING: *** One or more of the external libraries (ie libflac, libogg and
configure: WARNING: *** libvorbis) is either missing (possibly only the development
configure: WARNING: *** headers) or is of an unsupported version.
configure: WARNING: ***
configure: WARNING: *** Unfortunately, for ease of maintenance, the external libs
configure: WARNING: *** are an all or nothing affair.
```

My environmental variables are set up as so:

```
export SDKTARGETSYSROOT=/opt/poky-edison/1.7.3/sysroots/core2-32-poky-linux
export PATH=/opt/poky-edison/1.7.3/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin:/opt/poky-edison/1.7.3/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/i586-poky-linux:$PATH
export PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT/usr/lib/pkgconfig
export CONFIG_SITE=/opt/poky-edison/1.7.3/site-config-core2-32-poky-linux
export OECORE_NATIVE_SYSROOT="/opt/poky-edison/1.7.3/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux"
export OECORE_TARGET_SYSROOT="$SDKTARGETSYSROOT"
export OECORE_ACLOCAL_OPTS="-I /opt/poky-edison/1.7.3/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr/share/aclocal"
export PYTHONHOME=/opt/poky-edison/1.7.3/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr
export CC="i586-poky-linux-gcc  -m32 -march=core2 -mtune=core2 -msse3 -mfpmath=sse -mstackrealign -fno-omit-frame-pointer --sysroot=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT"
export CXX="i586-poky-linux-g++  -m32 -march=core2 -mtune=core2 -msse3 -mfpmath=sse -mstackrealign -fno-omit-frame-pointer --sysroot=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT -I${SDKTARGETSYSROOT}/usr/include/c++/4.9.1 -I${SDKTARGETSYSROOT}/usr/include/c++/4.9.1/i586-poky-linux"
export CPP="i586-poky-linux-gcc -E  -m32 -march=core2 -mtune=core2 -msse3 -mfpmath=sse -mstackrealign -fno-omit-frame-pointer --sysroot=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT"
export AS="i586-poky-linux-as  "
export LD="i586-poky-linux-ld   --sysroot=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT"
export GDB=i586-poky-linux-gdb
export STRIP=i586-poky-linux-strip
export RANLIB=i586-poky-linux-ranlib
export OBJCOPY=i586-poky-linux-objcopy
export OBJDUMP=i586-poky-linux-objdump
export AR=i586-poky-linux-ar
export NM=i586-poky-linux-nm
export M4=m4
export TARGET_PREFIX=i586-poky-linux-
export CONFIGURE_FLAGS="--target=i586-poky-linux --host=i586-poky-linux --build=i686-linux --with-libtool-sysroot=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT"
export CFLAGS=" -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types"
export CXXFLAGS=" -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types"
export LDFLAGS=""
export CPPFLAGS=""
export KCFLAGS="--sysroot=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT"
export OECORE_DISTRO_VERSION="1.7.3"
export OECORE_SDK_VERSION="1.7.3"
export ARCH=x86
export CROSS_COMPILE=i586-poky-linux-
```

but the flac library is there (in /opt/poky-edison/1.7.3/sysroots/core2-32-poky-linux/usr/local)! I have tried adding explicit paths to the flac library I compiled in a few places but nothing makes a difference. is there a specific place I should try tweaking the paths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Edison SDK actually came with FLAC already present, but an *older* version. Compiling my own version into a `usr/local/lib` location within my SDK did not update the pkgConfig, since it was placing the pkgconfig into `/usr/local/ib/pkgconfig`.

The easiest solution is to add the path, separated by a `:` into the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` variable in the environment setup script. example, line 4 becomes: 

`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT/usr/lib/pkgconfig:$SDKTARGETSYSROOT/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`

you could also pass the path during the `./config` step, but I think adding it to the variable is better long term solution.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue in **Ubuntu 20.04**, while installing another software, It might be helping someone else. I had to install the following way to resolve the issue.

```
  sudo apt install libsndfile1-dev
```